# How can I circumvent proxy on http requests when running a phonegap app in-browser

Tags: cordova, http, phonegap-cli

I have a PhoneGap 3.6.3 app. I'm running it locally using the phonegap cli using `phonegap serve` and opening the resulting IP in Chrome.

The app needs to make ajax calls to an external server. However, all http requests are being rerouted through `http://<local ip>/proxy/<external url>`.

For example, a http post to the API endpoint

`https://api.mymeq.com/json/user/login`

gets sent as

`http://192.168.2.59:3000/proxy/https%3A%2F%2Fapi.mymeq.com%2Fjson%2Fuser%2Flogin`

...to which the API server is responding with a 403. I would like to circumvent the local proxy entirely. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `phonegap browser run` instead of `phonegap serve` worked, because it doesn't route requests through a proxy.

Comment: Any solution to disable the proxy on `phonegap serve`

Comment: Hi @RashminJaviya did you find the solution?

Comment: @OliverKuchies No :( Let me know if you found something

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone ends up here, there is now a flag to do this. Just run `phonegap serve --no-proxy`.